# Blender Logo on Helmet how to export for spark ar

Tags: blender, spark-ar-studio

I have a hard hat that I added a logo to with a shrinkwrap in Blender.  But I can't seem to get the file exported to be able to use in SparkAR. I also can't get the meshes to join as one mesh. [image: Screen shot of blender workspace]

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to get the file exported

SparkAR supports .fbx format, you should select it when exporting.

Following 3D file formats supported:

```
FBX 2015 (binary and ASCII versions).
gITF 2 (binary and text versions).
OBJ.
DAE.
```

It's really easy to export too:

[image]

If this didn't solve your problem, provide more details on what's going wrong when you're exporting/importing your mesh.

---

> I also can't get the meshes to join as one mesh

To join meshes select them both and press `ctrl` + `j`